# Problema de conexión con ADO.NET Entity Data Model y MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6

Visual studio 2017 Me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: ese error dice que no tenes acceso. lo tenes?

Comment: En pasos anteriores, cuando te pide el server name, el usuario (root) y contraseña, al darle click a la opción de probar la conexion me dijo que fue exitosa